# Eror using bibliography IEEEtran

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, ieeetran, bibliographystyle

Can sameone tell me what happen to my latex, when I compile with

```
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran} 
\bibliography{dapus}
```

this eror coming

[image]

Comment: Please tell us how, i.e., with which options, you load the `natbib` package.

Comment: @Mico sorry, what do you mean with "which options" sir ?? I compile the .tex  file like usual and it works until I add the \bib part

Comment: Please give changing `\usepackage{natbib}` to `\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}` a try, followed by a full recompile cycle (LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more).